Make many object follow one path
I want to make many ices follow path I made but I stuck to find way to make it. the below picture here the blue one is single ice. and selection is ice path follower. the problem is, I dont know how to make many ice could follow the path I wanna do with randomize location. thanks for answer later!

Hello, give your objects a Follow Path constraint, play with the Evaluation Time of the curve, give a different Offset value to each of the objects Follow Path constraint?

Give your objects a Follow Path constraint, don't click on the Animate Path button, instead keyframe the Evaluation Time of the curve:

Give a different Offset value to each of the objects' Follow Path constraint so that they are at a different position on the curve, you can also keyframe this value:

